# CSS Header - Different Alignment

Tags: html, css

[Image of Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG9xG.png)

I want to add them to the same line so the header looks more tidy, what would be the correct code to use?

```css
.header{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 padding:10px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
}

.header a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.phone {
 text-align: right;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-right: 20px;
 align-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="products.html">Products</a>
<div class="phone"><a>Freephone: 0800 096 1617</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with `float`. Left for the the ones you want to go left, right for the phone number, and a `overflow: hidden` for the header.

```css
.header{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 padding:10px 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}

.header a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
        float: left;
}

.phone {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-right: 20px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="products.html">Products</a>
<div class="phone"><a>Freephone: 0800 096 1617</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should insert the Freephone: 0800 096 1617 to div class header and use Css position:absolute; right:(you can manipulate it to fix the freephone);

```
<div class="header">
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="products.html">Products</a>
<a class="freephone">Freephone: 0800 096 1617</a>
<div class="phone"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floating instead. The .clear class means to stop floating and it is neccessary. Also the phone does not need to be inside of a div and should have the id of phone instead of class of phone because there is only one phone element. You do not need the alignment and text-alignments at all.

```css
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#phone {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: right !important;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a id="phone">Freephone: 0800 096 1617</a>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this works as it wasn't tested because I am on mobile right now.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 padding:10px 0px;
 width:100%;
    float:left;
}

.header a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.phone {
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-right: 20px;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="products.html">Products</a>
<div class="phone"><a>Freephone: 0800 096 1617</a></div>
</div>
```

You have to add float:left; to  .header class and add float:right; to  .phone class